# Spring - Message driven channel adaptor - stop one specific concurrent consumer

Tags: spring-integration

I use spring integration components to wire my flow

- Message driven channel adapter picks messages from a weblogic queue.
- Uses a message converter and drops the message to a channel.
- This message from the channel is picked by a service activator.
- The pojo on service activator, does some data processing from db and then generates a report.
- For some reasons, I wanted to stop this consumer processing this request for reasons like (say pojo is taking too long to process)

What are my options?

- I tried these:

  - Exposed the spring's message drive channel adapter through JMX.
  - Used the stop method on message driven channel adapter.
  - This stops message driven channel adapter from picking new messages which is good.
  - But does not stop the one consumer already picked the message and currently in process.
  - How can i stop this process which is taking too long in my pojo?

Appreciate any help.

---

Update - 2

This is my code.

```
<bean id="myListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="destination" ref="requestQueue"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="threadPoolTaskExecutor"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
</bean> 

    <bean id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="10" />
    <property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="false"/>
</bean> 

<!-- Channel where service activator drops message to -->
<si:channel id="jmsOutChannel" />

<!-- This bean code calls DB to get some data and build a report/-->
<bean id="simpleExecutor" class="com.poc.reports.executors.SimpleCode"/>

<!-- Initialize service activator -->
<si:service-activator id="activator" input-channel="jmsInChannel"
    ref="simpleExecutor" method="execute" output-channel="jmsOutChannel">
</si:service-activator>

<!-- outbound adaptor for response Queue -->
<jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsout"
    channel="jmsOutChannel" destination="responseQueue" />
```

- I see that transaction is being maintained as you mentioned.
- But i see 5 to 10 threadPoolTaskExecutors being created since i have concurrent consumers = 5-10 (on adapter)
- Why should it create multiple threadPoolTaskExecutors? Should it not just use one threadpooltaskexecutor ?
- If i make concurrent consumer to 1, the it waits to pick up each message since its session transacted.

Appreciate your responses. Thank you.

---

Update - 3
- Maintaining a transaction within executor service when used with adapter works perfectly.

- Regarding killing a specific thread, I added a method named interruptNamedThread(String threadName) to executor service and exposed it via JMX.
- Triggered it and it sets the interrupt flag.
- I could check the interrupt status and terminate the thread by returning.(only since my test code is running in a loop and has the opportunity to check for the interrupt status).
- However it did not help my scenario.
- Since my thread does not run in a loop. It talks to DB and generates a report. End of thread. Returns to pool
- I wanted to end the thread when it takes too long to return from a DB call or third party library call (report generator).
- In this case it would not have a chance to check for the interrupt flag since its stuck in one of the call (DB or report generator).

In my use case,  is restarting the component the only way to kill a thread?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject a `TaskExcecutor` and set its `waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown` to false; this will cause it's `shutdown()` method to call `shutdownNow()` on the underlying `ExecutorService` when called  (or inject an `ExecutorService` and call its `shutdownNow()` method directly).

This will cancel (try to interrupt) active threads.

However, this won't help if your service is doing something that is uninterruptible - such as...

```
synchronize(foo) {}

lock.lock()
```

...or reading from a socket etc.

Comment: Thank you for the quick support. Implemented and I see two problems here. 1.) ExecutorService is shutting down all active threads. I need to shutdown only the problematic thread though. 2.) I am losing my jms transaction mode once it spawn threads using executor service. I would like to see it roll back the message if there is an error in side the executorservice spawned thread.

Comment: Where are you injecting the `ExecutorService`? Are you adding it to a channel? Using an external executor on the listener container (within the adapter, via the `task-executor` attribute) won't affect transaction semantics. If you only want to kill selected threads you will need to implement your own watchdog code. Perhaps a channel interceptor that schedules a `Thread.interrupt()` in `preSend()` and cancels the scheduled task in `postSend()`.

Comment: Just add my question with code details. Could you please review ?

Comment: There's only 1 executor, what you are seeing are Threads created by that executor (they have names `<beanName>-n`).

Comment: Appreciate your inputs Gary.                                   Added Update - 3 to my question. Please advice.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said in my original answer: "However, this won't help if your service is doing something that is uninterruptible...". If the thread is stuck reading from the DB driver's socket you are out of luck, unless you can somehow get a reference to the DB `Connection` the thread is using, and `close()` it.